# Windows Server 2012 R2 Folder Redirection doesn't work on Windows7, XP

Tags: windows-server-2012, folder-redirection

I have two domain controllers (Windows 2012R2) in one forest. I was playing around with Folder redirection. It worked on Windows 8.1 Computer but not on Windows 7 Pro. Three test user accounts have been created on the domain and all three document folders have been synced up from Windows 8.1.

"Also apply redirection policy to Windows 200, Windows 2000 Server ......" setting was checked there.
All users are grouped to "Folder Redirection User Group" and set up at GPO Security Filtering.

Still, on Windows 7, no redirection works.

**Edit1:** I suspect it could be due to SMB share version. W2012R2 supports SMB 3.02 and W7 uses SMB 2.
**Edit2:** Or it could be the Folder Relocation Root Path in GPO. \\dc2.abc.def.com\UserProfiles$ was used. Should I use \\dc2\UserProfiles$ ?
**Edit3:** After playing around, I don't think it is related to FQDN. Even setting up a share folder on the main domain controller (dc1) didn't solve this issue. Windows7 Client was not able to login the root of the shared folder i.e \dc1 and asking log in credentials. But those folders are able see on Windows 8 Computer.

Comment: I know it seems like you've given us a lot of detail, but you haven't. When you say it doesn't work what do you mean? What does GPRESULTS show? What folders are you redirecting? How are you determining that it isn't working?

Comment: @poeqwerty :I am testing with "Documents" folder redirection to \\dc2.<<domainname>>\UserProfiles$\ which is SMB share setup on FileServer. When user log in on the Win7 workstation, his documents folder should show the server location instead of local. GPResult shows the following: `The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        Local Group Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

         Folder Redirection Settings
            Filtering:  Denied (Security)`

Comment: OK, I hate to be the one to say this but isn't it obvious what the problem is? The GPO isn't applying because of your Security Filter. Remove the group from the Security Filter and add the Authenticated Users group and try again.

Comment: I followed this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649078.aspx. Removed "Authenticated Users" as instructed. The group entered in GPO Security Filtering contains all users I am testing.

Comment: I get that but GPRESULTS seems to suggest that your Security Filtering is denying the GPO from applying. So as a test, remove your Security Group and add the Authenticated Users group. If that resolves it then you know that your Security Group is the problem. also, after you created the group and added the users did you have the users log off and back on?

Comment: Backup Domain was turn off. Users now getting GPO correctly. In Win8, redirected folder name was shown and files are correctly seen. But in Win7, the same user has " error 502 access denied". The domain controllers are brand new and nothing has setup yet. This redirection GPO is the first one. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after messing around and searching on the net.
I got the idea from [this spicework forum](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/290724-windows-server-2008r2-folder-access-permissions-issue). The shared folder was removed from the "Server Manager > File and Storage Services > Shares " and applied the NTFS permissions with a old school method. Right click on the folder in the Windows Explorer, go to properties, select security and modify appropriate permissions.

It is a bug in the Server Manager (build number -- 6.3.9600.16384, date 8/21/13). If the folder is created from the Server Manager, only Windows 8 computers will get UNC path access. And XP and Windows 7 got an log in screen whenever that shared folder is accessed. It may be due to SMB versions. The servers that I am testing are HP Proliant DL320e Gen8 v2 and DL360p Gen8 v2.